# Group results where specific ID in a while-loop

Tags: php, while-loop, statements

```
Table with data:

id   score   inputid
1      1        1
2      4        1
3      3        1
4      1        2
5      2        2
6      3        5
7      1        6
8      1        6

while ($stmt_score->fetch())
{
 if($bind_inputid == '1') $array['score'][0] += $bind_score;
 if($bind_inputid == '2') $array['score'][1] += $bind_score;
 if($bind_inputid == '5') $array['score'][2] += $bind_score;
 if($bind_inputid == '6') $array['score'][3] += $bind_score;
}
```

As stated above I want to sum all results with specific ID. But since there will be more $bind_inputid ID's, my question is, how to make automatic statements for more results of an Id's ?

It has to be done in while loop not with mysql select.
PHP Lang.
Thx.

Comment: How about at least mentioning the programming language you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your result is sorted by `inputid`:

```
$inputid_curr = -1;
$score_array_index = -1;
while ($stmt_score->fetch())
{
 if($inputid_curr != $bind_inputid)
 {
  $score_array_index = $score_array_index + 1;
  $inputid_curr = $bind_inputid;
 }

 $array['score'][$score_array_index] += $bind_score;
}
```

Comment: @Cameleon - Creating more variables (use more space) often solve many problems.